# Why is my time not coming back as expected?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I checked WHM/cPanel on my server, and it has the Server Time set to United States Central Time, which is where I'm located.

I'm using the following:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('now');
$timefrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$timestamp);
```

Right now it's 2020-08-07 at 10:26 PM central time as I'm typing this, so I'm expecting to get back a value of `2020-08-07 22:26:00`.

However, I'm getting back a value of `2020-08-08 03:26:41`, which is 5 hours ahead of my actual time right now.

I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");` before the `$timestamp`

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/182294d79f7bb66b7d3075fccfd552919eb03767) `Output = 2020-08-07 22:36:21`

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
$timestamp = strtotime('now');
$timefrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$timestamp);
echo $timefrom;
```

Comment: Or set it in your [`php.ini`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone): `date.timezone`

Comment: @DrewAngell You are welcome. Glad i could you! Happy coding.